# hierarchic database and recursive data display in powerBI

Tags: database, recursion, powerbi, dax, hierarchical-data

So I'm currently working on some powerBI stuff, and I have a database table which is hierarchic, meaning I have something like this:

__id___Place______id_parent

1. London_____null
2. Paris________null
3. Madrid_____null
4. MyInc_________1
5. Building1_____4
6. Building2_____4
7. Floor1________5
8. Floor2________5

And i'd like to display it like so:

- London

  - MyInc

    - Building1

      - Floor1
      - Floor2
    - Building2
- Paris
- Madrid

Of course I have way more data, and some sub divisions everywhere
Any idea how I can achieve that?

Thanks by advance for your support

Comment: Parent-Child relationship, that mean we need here a dax FUNCTION PATH
read about all of this
https://dax.guide/path/

Comment: thanks a lot, didn't now about that DAX function :)